# How to convert multiple sheets in an excel workbook to csv files in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

I have a excel workbook that contains 8 sheets with different alphabetical names. i want to create csv files for each of these sheets and store it in a folder in python. Currently i am able to do this for a single sheet from the workbook but i am struggling to make a workflow on how to convert multiple sheets and store them as csv in a single folder. Here is my code for now:

```
import pandas as pd
my_csv=r'C:\Users\C\arcgis\New\NO.csv'
data_xls = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\C\Desktop\plots_data1.xlsx", "NO", index_col=0)
p=data_xls.to_csv(my_csv, encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to get all of the sheets, you can pass `sheet_name=None` to the `read_excel()` call. This will then return a dictionary containing each sheet name as a key, with the value being the dataframe. With this you can iterate over each and create separate CSV files.

The following example uses a base filename with the sheetname appended, e.g. `output_sheet1.csv` `output_sheet2.csv`:

```py
import pandas as pd

for sheet_name, df in pd.read_excel(r"input.xlsx", index_col=0, sheet_name=None).items():
    df.to_csv(f'output_{sheet_name}.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

It assumes that all of your sheetnames are suitable for being used as filenames.